# How can get data from mysql server from apps written by JQueryMobile and Phonegap?

Tags: jquery, android

I have create Android apps using JqueryMobile and PhoneGap.
How can I send request to mysql server and get back the results?
I have researched for few days but still no idea
Please help to solve

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ajax to talk with a php script, which actually does send the request to the mysql server and prepares the result, and after that you can display it with Ajax, to make it more "real-time" or to give it a "mobile feel".

**Resources:**
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax for that.. jquery has a great Ajax function!